# Javascript function scopes

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have function `bar` which I need to call. I'm new to using callbacks, from what I understand the callback is still inside the scope of the ajax so it can't see `bar`. Is it possible to call bar on ajax success? `bar` is defined in module `top`.

```
define(["top"], function() {
    function foo(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://asdf/qwer",
            success: function(response) {
                callback(response);
            }
        });
    }
    foo(function(response) {
        bar(response);      
    });
});
```

Comment: Which module loader do you use (the "define" function)? The availability of bar depends on it and the code of the top module.

Comment: How is `bar` defined in the `top` module. Is it an object with a property `.bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `top.js` looks similar to this:

```
define( function() {
  return {
    'bar': function( data ){
             // some code here
           }
  };
} );
```

(Note that the function has to be exported/returned here!)

You can access the `bar()` function like this:

```
define(["top"], function( top ) {
    function foo(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://asdf/qwer",
            success: function(response) {
                callback(response);
            }
        });
    }
    foo(function(response) {
        top.bar(response);      
    });
});
```

See the [require.js doc on working with dependencies inside a `define()` function](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep).

You should add a parameter to the function inside `define()` for every required module. In the example case this is the `top` parameter. Afterwards you can call all exported properties of the requirement module by using this parameter.

Comment: There is 2-3 redundant functions here though. You just need `success: top.bar` if it's only used once. If there is multiple ones you just need `success: callback` and `foo(top.bar)`